# Ticket drafting algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to write a program to automate a ticket draft.

We have a certain number of season ticket passes and want to split up the tickets among a group of people.  There are X number of games, Y number of season passes, and Z number of people.  Each of Z people has ranked the X games.

My code basically goes through the draft order and back picking out the tickets from their ranking if available, otherwise, picking the next highest ranking.  For the most part it works.  The problem is, there's a point where most of the tickets are taken and the remaining tickets left are ones you already have so you just don't pick them.  People therefore have different numbers of tickets.  Is there a good way to get around this?

Comment: You are allotting a season pass (from Y) for a game (from X) to a person (from Z) depending on the preference he has given for that game. This much I understood. I didn't understand "there's a point where most of the tickets are taken and the remaining tickets left are ones you already have so you just don't pick them" ... please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there were no preferences involved, this would be a straight min-cut max flow problem.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem, as follows:

Create a source vertex A.  From A, create Z vertices, one for each person.  The capacity can be infinite (or very, very large).  Create a sink B, and create X vertices, one for each game, linked to B; the capacity should be Y (you have Y tickets per game).  From each person, link to each game they've ranked, with capacity 1.

If you look at the wiki link above, there are about 10 algorithms to solve this basic problem.  Find one you understand and can implement yourself, because you'll need to modify it slightly.  I'm not familiar with all of them, but the ones I know about have a step 'pick an edge' or 'pick a path.'  You should modify the 'how you pick an edge' logic to take the priority ordering of the games into account.  I'm not sure exactly what the ordering should be (you'll probably need to experiment), but if you say the lowest ranked game is 1, the next is 2, up to X, then a score like 'ranking of the edge - number of games the person is already signed up for' might work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have X games and Y season passes, presumably there are X*Y tickets available to give to the Z people, right?

This sounds like it could be treated as an optimization problem, but to do so you have to identify your main goals?  I'm guessing you want each person to receive X*Y / Z tickets (split them evenly), but maybe not.  I'm guessing you also want to maximize the aggregate satisfaction (defined in some way according to the rankings) in tickets.  You would probably want to give a large penalty in satisfaction for a person if he receives more than 1 ticket for the same game.  I believe this last aspect might be why the straight draft approach is not the best, but I could be mistaken.

Once you are clear on what you are trying to optimize (if this is indeed an optimization problem), then you can consider the best approach to the problem.  This could be your own custom-built solution, or you could try an existing technique (genetic algorithm, etc.).  Before doing so though it is important that you frame the problem properly.

Comment: Yes, each person should receive an even number of tickets.  And each person should receive tickets in accordance with their rankings of those tickets.  The problem is that I don't want people receiving more than one tickets for the same game.

Comment: I'm thinking my algorithm would be something like "pick next highest ranked ticket, unless this results in a state which would leave someone with a duplicate ticket"

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a variant of the [Stable Marriage Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) or the [Stable Roommates Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem) for which there are known algorithms for solving.